# Difference between Twitter's user and application rate limits

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

The Twitter's API documentation is quite confusing for me.

[It says](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update.html) that rate limits for statuses/update are `300* per user; 300* per app`

Does it mean that each of the users can do 300 tweets/retweets? Or it means that all users can do 300 tweets/retweets together per time window?

Thank you for attention!

Answer (score 0):

This [announcement](https://twittercommunity.com/t/new-post-endpoint-rate-limit-enforcement-begins-today/115355) may help to clarify the information. At an overall application level, it is not possible to post more than 300 Tweets and/or Retweets inside that window, regardless of the number of users, unless you've applied for elevated access to the API.